# import with require that works fine on windows but not on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu

Here is my file tree :

```
> appointment/    
>     db/
>         db.js
>     appointment.js
```

And in my appointment.js i made a :

```
require( './../appointment/db/db' ); //init database
```

It works perfectly on windows but  on ubuntu 16.04 i have a error cannot find module './../appointment/db/db'

if anyone have any idea.

regards and thanks

Comment: `appointment` is named something different maybe? Why not just use `require( './db/db' );` ?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara  you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Alexander the ./db/db solution work fine on ubuntu & windows/